# Filling a polygon with rectangles

Tags: algorithm, web, geometry

I have a fairly smooth polygon, say an ellipse with bulges and dents converted to polygon straight lines. I wish to fill this polygon with as few rectangles as possible, but as many as to maintain accuracy in small corners in the polygon. The rectangles may be any size, and of any amount.

The reason for this is doing a hit test on a web page on the polygon. The only practical way is to fill it with divs and do hit tests on all the divs.

Of course there will be a minimum square size for any rectangle, lest we more than just approximate the polygon and recreate it with pixel size rectangles.

Comment: This seems to be an instance of [Point in polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, if you want to **exactly** represent a digital shape with rectangles, you will need at least as many rectangles as there are pixels on the outline forming corners. If you think of a digital straight edge at 45°, that means one rectangle per pixel. This is a serious limitation. (And don't even think of non-digital shapes.)

This said, you accept to approximate the shape with a certain error, and I suggest that you first shrink the shape by a constant factor, up to you: you will overlay a grid on the shape an decide whether every tile belongs to the shape or not. Doing this, you turn your shape in a binary image with "big pixels", and the challenge is now to decompose this image in rectangles (exactly this time).

I suggest a simple greedy strategy such that you try to find a large rectangle that fits entirely, and then repeat with the parts that remain.

If you apply a [morphological erosion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_(morphology)) operation with a larger and larger rectangular structuring element, you will find the largest rectangle the fits in the shape image. In theory, you should try all combinations of width and height and keep the largest area or perimeter; this is a large amount of work. I would recommend to try with growing squares first, and when you found the largest square to continue in the direction that allows it.

After you have found a large rectangle, erase it from the shape image and start again, until you completely erase it.